# Class private member wont change in function

Tags: c++, class, scope, member-access

```
using namespace std;

class map
{
    private:
        float result= 0;
    public:
        void func_1();
        void setres(float counter);
        float getres();
};
void map::setres(float counter)
{
    result= counter;
}
float map::getres()
{
    return result;
}
void map::func_1()
{
    float num_0=0, num_1=0, sum=0, i;
    
    map run;
    
    cout << run.getres() << " Result." << endl;
    if(result != 0)
        cout << "We already have a result saved and it's: " << run.getres() << endl;
    else
    {
        cout << "Give me first number: ", cin >> num_0;
        cout << "Give me second number: ", cin >> num_1;
        sum= num_0+num_1;
        cout << "Result is: " << sum << endl;
    }
    cout << "The program will save the result." << endl;
    run.setres(sum);
    cout << "The saved result is: " << run.getres() << "\nPress 1 to repeat the function and check\nif the result is saved." << endl;
    cin >> i;
    if(i==1)
        run.func_1();    
}

int main()
{
    map go;
    go.func_1();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why the private variable **result** is not saved. And how can i make it work.

Then i start compiling it works fine, private result is changing, but then i reopen the function, the result is back to 0 and i wanted it ro be the last result.

Example:
I put 4
I put 7
Sum is 11
And saved result is 11
Then i press 1 to go to the start the result is 0 again, but i wanted it to be 11 not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the function you are creating a local variable of the type map

```
map run;
```

the data member result of which is changed. That is the function does not change the data member result of the object for which the function is called.

Moreover for example in this code snippet

```
cout << run.getres() << " Result." << endl;
if(result != 0)
```

you are accessing the data member result of two different object. In the first statement

```
cout << run.getres() << " Result." << endl;
```

you are accessing the data member of the local object `run` while in the next statement

```
if(result != 0)
```

you are accessing the data member result of the object (the object `go` declared in main) for which the member function is called.

So remove the declaration in the function

```
map run;
```

and instead of expressions like for example `run.getres()` use either just `getres()` or `this->getres()`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your function is not using members of the object the method is called on. Instead you create a new instance inside the function:

```
void map::func_1()
{
    float num_0=0, num_1=0, sum=0, i;
    
    map run;  // <---------- here
    //...
```

Thats why every time you call the function you get a new fresh object. You do not need to create that instance. You already create one in `main` and inside the member functions you can access its members. As a fix you can remove all `run.` from the code. Eg

```
cout << run.getres() << " Result." << endl;
```

->

```
cout << getres() << " Result." << endl;
```

or if you prefer

```
cout << this->getres() << " Result." << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is saved to `run`, and `run.func_1()` is called for checking, but then `run.getres()` is called there. This `run` is new `map` object and differ from the `run` in which the data is saved.

You checked `result != 0`, but you used `run.getres()` to print the result. Inconsisitency here.

Instead of

```
    cout << run.getres() << " Result." << endl;
    if(result != 0)
        cout << "We already have a result saved and it's: " << run.getres() << endl;
```

You should do

```
    cout << result << " Result." << endl;
    if(result != 0)
        cout << "We already have a result saved and it's: " << result << endl;
```

or

```
    cout << getres() << " Result." << endl;
    if(getres() != 0)
        cout << "We already have a result saved and it's: " << getres() << endl;
```